# Using .map in <div> tag - react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would really appreciate any help.
So the project is a react project.

Here is what I fetch:
[fetching a request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WelCP.png)

Here is what I respond from server:
[Response from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2QG3.png)

I tried on Postman to see what type of json I am receiving.
Here is what it returns:
[Postman test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg6IE.png)

The problem I am having is that I am unable to map the data received.
I want to just show the received data in a nice way on front page once the link is entered.

Is it possible to map it inside div tag?
Or is there another way of doing it?

***Please note the the project is written as functional component***

Comment: Include code in your question using the code formatting option ({}) icon in the header, not images.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your component will look

```js
export default function App() {
  let data = [{ number: "1", other: "some data" }];
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <div>{item.other}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hardcoded the data outside the function

```js
import React from 'react'

const data = [{ number: "1. ", other: "some data" }];

const SomeData = () => {
return (
    <div>
        {data.map(list => (
            <li>{list.number}{data.map(item => (
                <span>{item.other}</span>
            ))}</li>
        ))}


    </div>
)
}

export default SomeData
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pseudo code, I did not test it, but it will look similar to this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    // the data you retrieved from server
    const data = [
      { number: 1, date: 'today', startTime: '09:00', endTime: '00:00'},
      { number: 12, date: 'today', startTime: '08:00', endTime: '00:00'},
    ]
    
    return(
      data.map(item => (
        <div>{item.number}</div>
      ))
    )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, you receive array of objects that you want to display, you can use the array method `map` to create a list of divs like this:

```
function createDOM() {
    return data.map(dataItem => {
        <div>
            // Code to display your data
        </div>
    });
}

return (
    <div>
        {createDOM()}
    </div>
)
```